# JSON Parsing to be displayed in android phone

Tags: php, android-studio

How can I convert or generate JSON from xampp php file localhost to be displayed on android mobile app?

Comment: how can we help without any info about the actual problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP Json encode data

```html
$data['postId'] = 123;
$data['title'] = "Your titile";
$data['permalink'] = "http://smddtech.com";
$data['content'] = "your content";
$data['date'] = "2017-03-05";
$return['data'] = $data;
echo json_encode($return);
exit();
```

You can get your data by Volley response. [See google volley documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). Please see the below code volley JSONObject response and how to loop with that.

```html
JSONArray newsItem=response.getJSONArray("data");
for (int loop=0;loop<newsItem.length();loop++)
{
    JSONObject tempObject=newsItem.getJSONObject(loop);
    int postId=tempObject.getInt("postId");
    String title=tempObject.getString("title");
    String permalink=tempObject.getString("permalink");
    String content=tempObject.getString("content");
    String date=tempObject.getString("date");
}
```